# How to combine two list items and form JSON data in Unity?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I was looking to convert items from two list to form JSON data.When I validated the JSON it is showing error.Code given below

```
public struct ListContainer
{

    public List<PlayerHandler> SaveValues;
    public List<PlayerMovement> NoteValues;


    public ListContainer(List<PlayerHandler> _saveVal,List<PlayerMovement> _noteVal)
    {
        SaveValues = _saveVal;
        NoteValues = _noteVal;

    }

}

//--Adding Two list into the container
ListContainer container = new ListContainer(getAlldata,playerNotes);

    //--Adding data in container into List<string> jsonstring
    jsonstring.Add(JsonUtility.ToJson(container));
```

Later I am saving the above the List of(CustomClass) **jsonstring** into a JSON file.The coding for saving it into the persistent path is given below.

```
public void Save()
{


    //--Get Text typed in the input box
    savedName = saveName.text;

    //--Combing list of string into a single string
    string jsons = string.Join(",", jsonstring);

    //Writing into a JSON file in the persistent path
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + savedName+".json" , FileMode.Create))
    {
        BinaryWriter filewriter = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        filewriter.Write(jsons);
        fs.Close();

    }

    saveButtonShow.SetActive(false);

}
```

When I check the json file from the path and try to validate it is showing error.JSON given below.

```
 {"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-2.383237361907959,"y":-5.711871147155762},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"movetype":1},{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":-4.0806732177734379,"y":5.998472213745117},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":1}],
"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":1,"notemsg":"First Move"}]},{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-2.383237361907959,"y":-5.711871147155762},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"movetype":2},{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":4.558084964752197,"y":-5.517238140106201},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},
{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":-4.0806732177734379,"y":5.998472213745117},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},
{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":4.3838324546813969,"y":4.650305271148682},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2}],
"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":2,"notemsg":"Second Move"}]}
```

The error it is showing is

```
Error: Parse error on line 61:
...: "First Move"   }]}, {  "SaveValues": [
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','
```

Comment: That's because the JSON ends there ... What you have is a `List<ListContainer>` or `ListContainer[]` there ... so it should be sorrounded by `[ ... ]`

Comment: But still I cant get values out of it....I tried  Debug.Log("Save value count = " + JNode[0]["NoteValues"]["notemsg"]); to get the 'First Move' output

Comment: well did you try `JNode[1]`? Also it depends on the library I guess ... according to the error message it seems like you are using something like https://jsoneditoronline.org (which uses [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)) for testing ... maybe the parsing library you are using within c# understands your given JSON better ... Please also see [Ruzihm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58425910/7111561) where he already posted a possible solution in c# as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58407055/how-to-load-selected-data-from-an-json-data-array-then-upon-clicking-next-button   This was my problem before adding [..... ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON validator you're using is expecting a single valid json value, but your file contains two json objects that are separated by a comma.

Consider putting your objects in an array by surrounding the collection of objects with square brackets.

Also, as [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) noted in the comments, "instead of `Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + savedName+".json"` you should rather always go for `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, savedName+".json")`:

```
public void Save()
{


    //--Get Text typed in the input box
    savedName = saveName.text;

    //--Combing list of string into a single string
    string jsons = "[" + string.Join(",", jsonstring) + "]";

    //Writing into a JSON file in the persistent path
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(
            Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, savedName+".json"), 
            FileMode.Create))
    {
        BinaryWriter filewriter = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        filewriter.Write(jsons);
        fs.Close();

    }

    saveButtonShow.SetActive(false);

}
```

Which would produce something like this:

```
[{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-2.383237361907959,"y":-5.711871147155762},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"movetype":1},{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":-4.0806732177734379,"y":5.998472213745117},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":1}],
"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":1,"notemsg":"First Move"}]},{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-2.383237361907959,"y":-5.711871147155762},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"movetype":2},{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":4.558084964752197,"y":-5.517238140106201},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},
{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":-4.0806732177734379,"y":5.998472213745117},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},
{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":4.3838324546813969,"y":4.650305271148682},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2}],
"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":2,"notemsg":"Second Move"}]}]
```

Comment: Note that instead of `Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + savedName+".json"` you should rather always go for `Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, savedName+".json")`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you resolve object bad string exceptions,
you have to **put them in array**, because they have same values and you are doing duplication of keys.

```
List<object> objList = new List<object>();
        objList.Add(list1);
        objList.Add(list2);
```

I create code sample for that

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KpZSiF

Answer (score 0):

You should store the containers in a list of containers, not jsons, and serialize just before you write to disk.

```
var containers = new List<ListContainer>();

(...)

ListContainer container = new ListContainer(getAlldata,playerNotes);
containers.Add(container);

(...)

string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(containers);
// maybe even = JsonUtility.ToJson( new { Players = containers } ); but that's not important.

// Save to file, your way or 
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, json);
```